# UI bug: Notification email address not remembered when question post initially fails

Tags: bug, status-declined, email-notification

I tested this on several sites in the network and the behavior is consistent.

When asking a question and changing the notification email address, the address is changed back to its initial value when the question fails to submit (I tested it with new user restrictions, e.g. new tags, too many URLs, etc.).

I consider this a bug, as I've **explicitly changed** the email address and the other contents are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want this to happen, because **it is changing the primary email on your account**.

Therefore, this means you would change the primary email on your account even on a failed submission (!).

Comment: It would not have to directly change the email, it would just have to remember that I wanted to change it when asking this question. So if I never successfully submitted the question I started to write, nothing would happen. But if I do, and I leave the change in the email, then it would be changed.

Comment: that's not now the implementation works; it loads the current value of your user email.

Comment: But it does somehow remember the other values (title, body, tags, etc.). Adding the email address to that if it was changed and using that one instead of the one from the account should be possible.